# How do I make the media-query wrap my divs?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm running Shopify Debut theme. I am attempting to edit the Hero section which is a text overlay with background image.

I have two divs that I created and I am able to place them next to each other. However, when I reduce the size of the screen to mobile, the div on the right side just gets shoved off the screen.

There is a media-query for each div (from the shopify theme). I think I need to edit this to change the display type of the divs, but I'm not sure. Can you advise? I have stripped-down code in jfiddle.

```
  @include media-query($small) {
max-width: $width-site;
padding-left: $gutter-site-mobile;
padding-right: $gutter-site-mobile;}
```

See fiddle for details:
https://jsfiddle.net/tulanejosh/dj7cskpp/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is not css, it is sass/scss .. so your mediaquery can't work because $small is not defined

you should post the compiled css

Comment: Thank you. I updated the jfiddle with the full scss. The two divs that I added are: <div class="hero-text-page-width text-left" id="one"> and <div class="hero-video-page-width" id="two">. I'm simply trying to get them to stack once the page goes mobile width.

Comment: you have to understand, that you are using a CMS, which uses a template-engine (smarty) .. this engine replaces vars in your code .. e.g. ´class="hero hero--{{ section.settings.hero_size }}{% if section.settings.title != blank or section.settings.text != blank or section.settings.button_label != blank %} hero__overlay{% endif %} box ratio-container lazyload js"´ ..  looking at your fiddle, one can just guess what would be after ´hero hero--´  .. you should try to isolate the RENDERED html and css, strip it down in a new file so you have only the rendered CSS and your two divs with wrapper-divs